# How to read giant CSV file by loop

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a base CSV. It is in the source:[311-Service](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Social-Services/311-Service-Requests-from-2010-to-Present/7ahn-ypff)
This base has about 11 GB. It is 19 million rows and 41 columns.

I want to take the information only about city: NEW JERSEY form column City.
I can use this inquiry only for 500,000 rows. It works!

```
NYPD = pd.read_csv('c:/1/311_Service_Requests_from_2010_to_Present.csv', nrows=500000, low_memory=False)
M = NYPD.loc[NYPD.City=='NEW JERSEY', :]
M.to_csv('c:/1/NJ_NYPD.csv')
```

I need information from all rows of the CSV file, not from only 500 000 rows. 
I think I need to use a loop and chunksize = 500,000, but I don't know how.

```
hunksize =500000  
    i = 0
    j = 1
    for df in pd.read_csv('c:/1/311_Service_Requests_from_2010_to_Present.csv', chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True, low_memory=False):
          df.loc[df.City=='NEW JERSEY', :]
          df.index += j
          i+=1
          df.to_csv('c:/1/NJ_NYPD.csv')
```

I don't want to translate CSV in to dbase method.

Comment: use `skiprows` argument

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the desired column at parse time:

```
my_filtered_csv = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=['City'])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about trying the API call :-

```
data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/fhrw-4uyv.json?city=NEW%20JERSEY
```

this loads json only for the specified city, then convert this json to your dataFrame

```
import requests
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = requests.get('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/fhrw-4uyv.json?city=NEW%20JERSEY')

json_normalize(json.loads(data.text))
```

[image]

P.S.:- They have some documentation with python pandas too :-

```
https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.cityofnewyork.us/fhrw-4uyv
```

P.P.S.:- I did not register for the service, so it shows only 50 records as to my knowledge.

Comment: looks promising - I will practice it tonight and I will give an answer if it works. thanks!!

Comment: @WojciechMoszczyński you are wellcome, keep us posted :)